# A PHP class for the common database operations?

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I'm a CS undergrad, so I don't have much experience. But while coding vanilla PHP projects, I found that I was repeating myself a lot with the CRUD operations. So overtime, I developed a single file called config.php that I use in all the projects where I use PHP as a backend (70% of the time). Basically, the workflow is like this: Get data, put it into an array, get the query, then call a function from config.php which will execute it for you without needing to call the database in the same file. My teammates all praised it for its simplicity. I worked with someone who didn't even know PHP and was able to get along because of the file.

That said, all these praises come from undergrads like myself. If someone can look at my file and give me constructive feedback I'd really appreciate it. I want to know if there are ways to improve it or if it's a really bad idea to do this from the get go.

```
<?php
class Connection
{
    private $conn;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $database = "dloc";
        $this->conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

        if ($this->conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $this->conn->connect_error);
        }
    }

    public function getConnection()
    {
        return $this->conn;
    }

    public function closeConnection()
    {
        $this->conn->close();
    }

    public function executeSelectQuery($query, $params = array())
    {
        $stmt = $this->prepareStatement($query, $params);
        try {

            if (!$stmt) {
                return array();
            }

            $stmt->execute();

            $result = $stmt->get_result();

            if (!$result) {
                return array();
            }

            return $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        } finally {
            $stmt->close();
        }
    }

    public function executeWriteQuery($query, $params = array())
    {
        $stmt = $this->prepareStatement($query, $params);
        try {

            if (!$stmt) {
                return false;
            }

            $result = $stmt->execute();

            return $result;
        } finally {
            $stmt->close();
        }
    }

    public function executeSelectOneRow($query, $params = array())
    {
        $stmt = $this->prepareStatement($query, $params);
        try {

            if (!$stmt) {
                return null;
            }

            $stmt->execute();

            $result = $stmt->get_result();

            if (!$result || $result->num_rows == 0) {
                return null;
            }

            return $result->fetch_assoc();
        } finally {
            $stmt->close();
        }
    }

    public function executeMultipleWriteQueries(array $queries)
    {
        $this->conn->begin_transaction();
        try {
            foreach ($queries as $queryData) {
                list($query, $params) = $queryData;
                $stmt = $this->prepareStatement($query, $params);

                if (!$stmt) {
                    $query = $queryData['query'];
                    $params = $queryData['params'];
                    $stmt = $this->prepareStatement($query, $params);
                    if(!$stmt){
                        throw new Exception($stmt->error);
                    }
                }


                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->close();
            }

            $this->conn->commit();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            error_log("Exception during executeMultipleWriteQueries: " . $exception->getMessage());

            $this->conn->rollback();
            return false;
        }
    }



    private function prepareStatement($query, $params)
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        if (!$stmt) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($params) {
            $types = $this->getBindTypes($params);
            $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$params);
        }

        return $stmt;
    }

    private function getBindTypes($params)
    {
        $types = '';
        foreach ($params as $param) {
            if (is_int($param)) {
                $types .= 'i'; // integer
            } elseif (is_float($param)) {
                $types .= 'd'; // double
            } elseif (is_string($param)) {
                $types .= 's'; // string
            } else {
                $types .= 'b'; // blob
            }
        }
        return $types;
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        $this->conn->close();
    }

}
?>
```

And usually I have repository files which will call instantiate this class i.e:

```
function getSheetById($sheetOneId) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM sheetone WHERE SheetOneId = ?";
        $connection = new Connection();
        return $connection->executeSelectOneRow($query, array($sheetOneId));
    }

    function insertSheet($sheetOneId, $material, $lengthAndWidth, $thickness, $quantity, $operator, $dateSent) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO sheetone (SheetOneId, Material, LengthAndWidth, Thickness, Quantity, Operator, DateSent) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $params = array($sheetOneId, $material, $lengthAndWidth, $thickness, $quantity, $operator, $dateSent);
        $connection = new Connection();
        return $connection->executeWriteQuery($query, $params);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes of course it's OK to have such a file. However, your Connection class is hardly related to actual CRUD operations. It's more a DAO, a database abstraction object.

Speaking of the code you provided, it's not a bad code for an undergraduate, though it can see a good rewrite. Better yet, just update your PHP version, as since 8.2 PHP has everything that your Connection class does.

So you can leave only the following code in the config file

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "dloc";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
```

and then rewrite following statements

```
$data = $conn->executeSelectQuery($sql, $params);
// to
$data = $conn->execute_query($sql, $params)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$data = $conn->executeWriteQuery($sql, $params);
// to
$data = $conn->execute_query($sql, $params);

$data = $conn->executeSelectOneRow($sql, $params);
// to
$data = $conn->execute_query($sql, $params)->fetch_assoc();
```

Though `executeMultipleWriteQueries` indeed warranted to exist, but you can have it as a function. And it needs to be rewritten as well

```
function executeMultipleWriteQueries(array $queries)
{
    try {
        $this->conn->begin_transaction();
        foreach ($queries as $queryData) {
            $this->conn->execute_query(...$queryData);
        }
        $this->conn->commit();
    } catch (Throwable $exception) {
        $this->conn->rollback();
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

Note that I removed that ambiguous behavior, when `$queryData` may contain either associative or enumerated array. You should decide on a single format and always use it.

Also, there is a HUGE downside in the way you are using your Connection class. You are creating a new connection every time a query gets executed. It's a BIG NO. A connection has to be created only once. Create it at the beginning of your script and then pass as a parameter to your classes.

Comment: Thanks! I'll implement these changes. I didn't know it's a bad idea to create a new connection every time a query is executed. While writing this code, I was inspired by the way we use the connection in WinForms.

Comment: For a very simple application that does strictly one query per call, it's not a big deal. But every app grows and does more and more queries per execution (some selects, some update, getting data from different tables, etc). In this case you will just kill your database server, overloading it with connections, and also degrade the performance as connection being a relatively costly operation

Comment: Later I will update my answer with more details, stay tuned

Answer (score 2):

## Closing PHP tag can be omitted

The file appears to only have PHP code (and nothing else like HTML). Per [the PHP documentation for PHP Tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php):

> If a file contains only PHP code, it is preferable to omit the PHP closing tag at the end of the file. This prevents accidental whitespace or new lines being added after the PHP closing tag, which may cause unwanted effects because PHP will start output buffering when there is no intention from the programmer to send any output at that point in the script.
>
> [image: screenshot of sample code in PHP documentation about closing tag]

## Calls to `close` methods could be removed

I see there is a `closeConnection()` method as well as a destructor (i.e `__destruct()`) method which both call the `close` method on the connection.

In [this review of *Proper use of mysqli->close();*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/221192/120114) YCS stated:

> *As for your question, in the average PHP script you don't have to close neither the statement nor the connection. PHP will close it for you automatically.*

It is somewhat surprising YCS did not appear to mention that in their answer. Unless you have a specific requirement that the connection be closed before the script is complete then those methods could be removed.

There are also three places where the `close` method is called on a prepared statement - i.e. in the `finally` blocks within methods `executeSelectQuery()`, `executeWriteQuery()` and `executeSelectOneRow()`. Per [the description of `mysqli_stmt_close` method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.close.php#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.close-description):

> Closes a prepared statement. `mysqli_stmt_close()` also deallocates the statement handle. If the current statement has pending or unread results, this function cancels them so that the next query can be executed.

If there isn't a concern about memory or other resources then the `finally` blocks could be removed along with the `try` wrappers.

## `match` statement could simplify `if`/`elseif`/`else` chain

The method `getBindTypes` contains an `if` followed by two `elseif`s and then an `else`. This can be simplified with a [`match` statement](https://www.php.net/match) using [non identity checks](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.match.php#example-406)

```
$types .= match (true) {
    is_int($param) => 'i', // integer
    is_float($param) => 'd', // double
    is_string($param) => 's', // string
    default => 'b', // blob
};
```

With this approach there is a single append assignment operator and fewer lines are occupied.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I also felt like the close methods could be removed seeing as how it currently has 0 references. But regarding the match statement, wow that's a game changer for me. Looks really clean and nice.

Comment: @sammymedawar only mind that you don't need it here, as well as entire getBindTypes method which is superfluous and can be dangerous to use. If your input happen to be numeric, it will be bound as numeric with catastrophic consequences. DELETE FROM table WHERE string_column=0 will wipe the entire table. DELETE FROM table WHERE string_column='0' will delete only rows where string_column contain 0. Using s for every parameter is safer and simpler than sniffing the type.